# Matplotlib plot's color changing automatically when not expected

Tags: python, matplotlib, operating-system, delete-file

i am seeing a wierd thing.

i have a program that loops over a list, plots a bar graph using matplotlib, saves the figure to a somefile.png in current dir, and sends an email attaching the picture, then deletes the image. ( next image will be saved at same location)

now, when i send just one email, the color of graph is the default blue.

but when i am sending multiple emails, i am seeing distortion in color . the different graphs are of completely different color, and the top of the graph is some mixed color

[image]

can anyone explain why ? and what can i do to avoid this ?

each plot is being done seperately.
and i had also given a 2s sleep time after deleting the image file

Comment: Its hard to know exactly without you code, but matplotlib cycles colors by default. You are likely not clearing your figure between creating the bar plots, and hence not resetting the cycle.

Comment: thanks a lot. i think thats the answer. but why the distortion happening ?

i could not reproduce the distortion with a simple dummy code.

i dont know why.

Comment: in my actual code, the file is being read, just after matplotlib saves it. I introduced a 2s time delay, but still distortion is happening in the images.
see this
![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/66209958/103304798-89c15800-4a2f-11eb-8f46-a3465c4c46db.png)

Comment: If you can't reproduce the error with simple dummy code, continue adding complexity (chunk-by-chunk) until you get the behavior back. At that point, you'll have identified the cause of the behavior

Comment: I think the error is the equals sign on line 23.

Comment: Again, you are not resetting the cycler, because you are not clearing the figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `plt.close()` after `plt.savefig(path)` solved the problem.

This solved the distortion issue, as well as got same color for all plots.

Thanks to [@Jody Klymak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3394386/jody-klymak) for commenting about "resetting the cycler"